# Upgrading symfony from 1.3 to 3

Tags: symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have symfony version 1.3 .
 **I wanted to know is it possible to upgrade from 1.3 to 3.** 
if yes then how we can do it ? or else we have to upgrade to 2 first and then go to  3

Comment: Wraping it as Anna suggested might work.  But basically, S1 and S2/S3 are completely different and there is no upgrade path.  I would suggest making a new S3 project, learn how Symfony 3 works then start implementing functionality from your S1 base.  But it will end up being a complete rewrite.  No need to go to S2 at all.

Comment: ok thanks , but writing everything is not good solution

Comment: Perhaps hiring a contractor?  Even though both frameworks start with the word Symfony they are completely different.  Like trying to upgrade an operating system between Windows and linux.

Comment: ohhhh . example of windows and unix was gud

Answer (score 5):

To upgrade from 1 to 2.0, you can use answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700648/porting-a-website-from-symfony-1-4-to-2-0):

> You may wrap your legacy project in a brand new sf2 project, by using
>   [this bundle](https://github.com/Ingewikkeld/IngewikkeldWrapperBundle). This way, you'll be able to migrate your project one
>   piece at a time, and new functionalities may be developed with sf2 as
>   soon as you get the wrapper to work. You may be interested by [this
>   post about migrating](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2012/02/migration-to-symfony2-continued/?utm_source=leaseweblabs.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=redirect).

Upgrading to Symfony 3.0
First, make your application run on Symfony 2.8 without errors. Then, install the [PHPUnitBridge](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge) component and fix all the reported deprecation issues. Now you are ready to upgrade to Symfony 3.0. You can also use any of these tools to spot and fix those deprecations:

- [Deprecation Detector](https://github.com/sensiolabs-de/deprecation-detector) ([details](http://symfony.com/blog/paving-the-way-for-symfony-3-with-the-deprecation-detector-tool))
- [Symfony Upgrade Fixer](https://github.com/umpirsky/Symfony-Upgrade-Fixer)

Comment: The [Bundle](https://github.com/Ingewikkeld/IngewikkeldWrapperBundle) u mentioned it compatibility is so far only confirmed with symfony 1.0 as [docs](https://github.com/Ingewikkeld/IngewikkeldWrapperBundle#known-issues--todo) so carefully when using it. 
I asked this quetion on one of symfony core devs in one of symfony community meetings and they answered me that the best way is to re-write code :(.

Comment: @Anna Adanchuk , what to do after 7 step of IngewikkeldWrapperBundle

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade from **Symfony 2.8 to 3.4** (at the moment), you might find useful this tool:

- [RectorPHP](https://github.com/RectorPHP/Rector)

It is AST-based automated refactoring tool, to use in CLI.

At the time of writing this it contains around ~60 changes. Still growing every day.